# Is there a finite field where the primitve elements form a additive sub group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Is there a finite field where the primitve elements form a additive sub group?

I basically stuck at this problem because primitive elements generate all non zero element of the field so the sub group couldn't be additive without it's 0 element.

At least that is what I think but I'm not even sure about that.

Can someone explain why it is not possible or if possible could you give me an example?

Comment: Indeed, $0$ is not primitive and that's it

Comment: Thank you for confirming it.

Comment: Perhaps it's more interesting to ask whether the primitve elements *plus* $0$ can form a additive subgroup.